# Creating an Interface for data being returned from the service throws error

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm creating an interface for the data being return from the service, but when I apply the interface for this data to my mockData it says
Type 'string' is not assignable to type '[]'.
Below is the data being returned from service and the my interface:

```
{

      selectionGroups: [
          [ 'TAXES',
            'RETIREMENT'
          ],
          [
              "RMD",
              "PARTICIPANT"
          ],
          [
              "VOYAGER",
              "ADVISOR"
          ],
          [
              "TECHNICAL_SUPPORT"
          ]
      ]
  }
```

// interface:

```
export interface ContactInfoSelectionResponse {
    selectionGroups: Array<[][]>
}
```

Comment: `[][]` is specifically "an array of empty arrays", which is not what you mean.

Comment: I'd say you want `selectionGroups: Array<Array<string>>` or possibly `selectionGroups: Array<[string, string?]>` depending on if you care about the length of the string arrays.

Comment: Is there any constraint on the length or content of the arrays?  Is it always a bunch of strings?

Comment: @jcalz -> it works. Thanks!